# labview Instrument I/O assistant

Tags: installation, labview, drivers

I need to interface RHODE & SCHWARTZ FSV spectrum analyzer with my laptop. For this I have installed R&SSV instrument drivers. I thought that for interfacing I need instrument I/O assistant, but I got error like in below image. For that I have installed NIVISA and NI4882280 drivers. But again I'm getting the same error. Is this correct way to install instrument I/O assistant? Is Instrument I/O assistant needed for interfacing of instrument?

[image]

Comment: What specific action causes this error message to appear?

Comment: In functions palette under instrument I/O we have this option instrument I/O   assistant if we click on that, the error message will be displayed. But we are getting a doubt that is this instrument I/O needed for interfacing instruments. Because  We have installed R&S FSV drivers for interfacing the spectrum analyzer.

Comment: Have you read the manufacturer's documentation for their drivers at https://www.rohde-schwarz.com/en/applications/how-to-use-rohde-schwarz-instruments-with-labview-application-note_56280-72195.html (which I found very quickly from a web search) ? It doesn't make any mention of the Instrument I/O Assistant. Have you tried using the drivers to perform a simple operation on the instrument and if so what happens?

Comment: That's right. Today I found that in a video. There is no need of instrument I/O assistant.  So there is no need to bother about that. R&S FSV drivers are enough for interfacing the spectrum analyzer. I am trying to do the programming using the vis.